# Changing traefik's realm / AuthName

Tags: reverse-proxy, basic-authentication, traefik

I am using `traefik` with `basic auth`, but now I want to set a specific `realm` (Apache enables this with the `AuthName` parameter ) to customize the prompt given to my users (the message will explain to them how and where to find the credentials).

Is this feature (realm customization) implemented in `traefik`, and if yes, how would I use this (prefered solution would be via compose labels, but traefik.toml is just fine too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such feature implemented in traefik. Apparently you can have `realm` with [digest authentication](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#digest-authentication), but it also appears broken, I filed a report [here](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3837).